# C# Problem Running WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-access-security, securityexception

Having some problems in my WPF application using Visual Studio 2010, building in C#. The error coming up at the moment is:

> SecurityException was unhandled by user code

The following is the code when I click a button, it checks the size of a text file, and if it has volume or not colors the background of a button called 'ButtonToday'.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Gets current date and puts it into string.
    string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
    string yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");

    TextBoxToday.Text = "" + today;
    TextBoxYesterday.Text = "" + yesterday;
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo("D:\\Client1\\2011.02.14.log");
    {
        if (f.Length > 0)
            ButtonToday.Background = Brushes.Green;
        else
            ButtonToday.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help. I am a n00b.

Comment: Does the user account running the application have access to ("D:\\Client1\\2011.02.14.log") ?

Comment: it will be helpful if you post the stack trace and source of the exception. Use the try..catch block shown by @DashRantic.

Comment: The error I got back from the suggestion below is this:
The application that failed was: Demand. The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission. The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you (or your application) doesn't have the proper permissions open the file. Check and make sure that you can access the file yourself through the filesystem, sounds like you probably can't.

[edit]You do have permission to read the file, then?  Odd.  Definitely try the below then, you won't know exactly what's going on until you get more detail from the exception being thrown.[/edit]

Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Gets current date and puts it into string.
    string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
    string yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
    TextBoxToday.Text = "" + today;
    TextBoxYesterday.Text = "" + yesterday;

     try
     {
         FileInfo f = new FileInfo("D:\\Client1\\2011.02.14.log");
         {
             if (f.Length > 0)
                 ButtonToday.Background = Brushes.Green;
             else
                 ButtonToday.Background = Brushes.Red;
         }
     }
     catch ( SecurityException ex )
     {
         ex.Message;
     }
}
```

Place a breakpoint over the `ex.Message;` line, then run your program in debug mode.  Hover over the variable `ex` when you get to it and read the error messages, should give you more information as to what is going on.  Hope this helps!

Comment: What's the namespace needed for 'SecurityException' please?

Comment: I believe the namespace is System.Security; , or try System.Security.SecurityException;

Comment: The error I got back roughly said at the end: 
> The type of the first permission that failed was System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission The Zone of the assembly that failed was MyComputer
Does this make any sense?

Comment: Your application is unable to read the file you're pointing it towards.  I'm assuming the file you're trying to check and the app you're running are both on the same local machine?  If so, double-check your user account's permissions on the file the program is trying to access.  You may be able to open the file because you're running as an administrator, but if Visual Studio isn't running in Admin mode, it won't be able to access the file.  So try either running Visual Studio in Administrator mode, or give your user account full read permissions on the file you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you can see the file through windows explorer, it might be an Administrative permissions issue.

Try running visual studio as an administrator (right-click on it's icon, and pick "Run as Administrator") and see if that helps.

Alternatively you could select the folder in windows explorer and give the "Users" group permission to read it. [Here's a place to start](http://www.dkszone.net/how-to-change-filefolder-permissions-in)